# Switching between between main and pop-up form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I lock (and make it look faded) a parent form while the child form is active? I tried to make the child form topmost but that just made it always visible and I can still edit the parent form. I want to be unable to operate on the main form while the child form is running in VS2012, C#. This is the code I used to call the second form...

```
private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: How is this question related to visual studio? Would it be different in another editor? Why is it not tagged with Windowm, XAML or any other relevant tag?

Comment: It was simply for the purpose of clarity, that's the IDE I'm using,

Comment: @TomTom Let's not get crazy here.  You could just edit the question, seeing how he's a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple way is to use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` on the child form.  This will prevent any interaction with the main form.  This is also a neat way of passing back results.  There are many other ways, of course.

Example:

```
private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);
    newForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

See MSDN for further details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That works just the way I want it to B.K. I would also like to know if the data I work with can be saved/passed back to the original form, or even to a textfile/database?

Comment: @Sensei Yes, but all those are different things and can be approached in different ways.  If, for example, you wan to return results other than `DialogResult` enumeration returned by the ShowDialog() method, you could create a public method in your pop-up form, say `ShowDialogWithResults()` which uses `ShowDialog()` within it and then returns the results to the main form.  You can see possible implementation of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764736/is-it-possible-to-overload-the-showdialog-method-for-forms-and-return-a-differen

Answer (score 0):

Just add Hide() for Current Running Form,

```
 private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);
                this.Hide();//hide old form
                newForm.Show();
            }
```

Comment: I suppose this would work since, the only problem that may have arose was that each time I terminated the child form, a new instance of the parent form was created so I ended  up with duplicates of the same form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form.ShowDialog to create dialog which will open on top of parent form and will not allow to edit parent until you close child

```
private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);
            newForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna run the form2 in separate thread and set topmost = true, the form1 will function unblocked, but the form2 will run whatever you want unblocked too. Is this what you want?

```
namespace TestModal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thrd = new Thread(newwindow);
            thrd.IsBackground = true;
            thrd.Start();
        }

        private void newwindow()
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.TopMost = true;
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```